# How do I pipe ffmpeg to opusenc on Windows?

Tags: windows, audio, ffmpeg, mp3

On Linux you can do something like this:

```
(bash)
ffmpeg -i foo.mp3 -f wav - | opusenc --bitrate 64 - bar.opus
```

This is neat, because it means you don't have to write the WAV data to disk before passing it to opus, so the encoding happens on the fly in memory instead.

I have both `ffmpeg` and `opusenc` installed on Windows, and since Powershell has pipes I expected to be able to do something similar, so I'm trying this:

```
(PS)
> ffmpeg -y -i .\foo.mp3 -f wav - | .\opusenc.exe --bitrate 64 - bar.opus
```

What I'm expecting to happen: ffmpeg should be piping wav audio directly to opusenc for encoding

What happens instead: it seems to *only* run ffmpeg without passing the data on to opusenc, indicated by constant RAM growth of the PS process and no output from opusenc.

Comment: Whether someone will use PS or CMD in Windows 10 to run CLI commands with piping is a complete coin flip. Yes, it's a PS issue but the person asking the question will not know that when asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular `cmd.exe` instead of Powershell. The exact same command works in cmd, but does not in PS:

```
> ffmpeg -y -i .\foo.mp3 -f wav - | .\opusenc.exe --bitrate 64 - bar.opus
```